# Fluentd is not exploding json logs

Tags: containers, fluentd

I am unable to explode my json in the fluentd. When I send this json to docker to execute

```
docker run --log-driver=fluentd --log-opt fluentd-address=docker.for.mac.localhost:24226 --log-opt tag="docker" python echo '{"hi":"yo"}'
```

This is the message my fluentd shows

```
2020-08-13 11:11:48.000000000 +0530 docker: {"log":"{\"hi\":\"yo\"}","container_id":"4d26713583925d70781c3840b886e72c3c1866c67d2fe329e3bf9c16de8cd328","container_name":"/nervous_newton","source":"stdout","tag":"docker"}
```

My log is a json which is not exploded to key and value

Here is my fluentd config

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24226
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match docker>
  include_tag_key true
  @type stdout
</match>

<filter docker>
      @type parser
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
      key_name log
      reserve_data true
    </filter>
```

I am running on my mac machine with fluentd version as 1.0.2 ruby="2.4.2"

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

How stupid of me. The order is important. filter should be before match